# Question Relevancy Filtering

Tags: support

I notice that stack overflow shows me a lot of questions that are outside my area of expertise.

Is there a way I can get the website to filter topics shown to me to be of maximum relevance, rather than "hotness" ?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is add to your list of favorite tags.  Questions in these tags will be shaded so they are more easily distinguishable.  They will also have more of a weight for display on the Stackoverflow home page.

You can also list questions from specific tags using either the UI (click on any tag) or search by using `[tagname]` as a search term (ie- the name of the tag surrounded by square brackets).